# Unable to perform get request.Getting 400 bad Request error

Tags: robotframework, web-api-testing

Here is my code

```
**Settings**
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    RequestsLibrary
Library    Collections
Library    JSONLibrary    
Library    JsonValidator 
**Variables**

${Base_URL}  http://192.168.0.000:8000 (Example) 
${json_path}  C:/LogAPI.json (Example) 
${req}  /v1/api/logs (Example)

*** Test Cases ***
APITesting   
      Create Session    Get_JobId    ${Base_URL}
  ${json}=  Catenate  { "time_zone": "Asia/Calcutta"} 
  Log To Console    ${json}    
  &{headers}  Create Dictionary  Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
  ${Response}=  Get Request     Get_JobId   ${req}    data=${json}  headers=${headers}
  ${code}=  Log To Console    ${Response.status_code}     
  Log To Console    ${Response.content}    
  Should Be Equal    ${code}    200
```

This is my Error

```
==============================================================================
APITesting                                                            {"time_zone": "Asia/Calcutta"}
400
400 Bad Request
| FAIL |
None != 200
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test1.Get-Logs                                                        | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

Comment: The documentation says that the `data` parameter should either be a dictionary or raw binary data. You're passing the string representation of a dictionary rather than an actual dictionary. Have you tried using an actual dictionary?

Comment: No I haven't tried actual dictionary, I m using string representation

Comment: I recommend you try using a real dictionary since that's what the documentation says to use.

Comment: can you tell how to use...

Comment: You've got two different json libraries in your import, I suggest you pick one and then  look for the keyword that converts your string into json.

Comment: Also your test isn't failing because of a 400 error, log to console doesn't return anything and you should be asserting ${response.status_code} is 200.